# Why can't I seem to unarchive objects in an iPhone app that were archived by an OS X app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an iPhone app that is mainly centered around grid patterns, so I have a Pattern class which contains an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays.  This class implements NSCoding, and it seems the following code works just fine in my iPhone app:

```
GridPattern * pattern = [GridPattern patternWithWidth:8 height:8];
[pattern setValueAtColumn:0 row:7 value:1];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:pattern toFile:@"test.pat"];
pattern = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"test.pat"];
```

If I debug the code above, I find after stepping over line 4, that I have a GridPattern object with the appropriate value set for column 0, row 7.

I have also written a Cocoa OSX application intended for creating patterns for the iPhone app, which also uses the same GridPattern class.  It can also load and save the patterns successfully.

What I wanted to do was:

- create and save the patterns in the OS X app

  2. add the pattern files into Resources group in XCode for the iPhone app; (I added it as `test.pat`)
  3. unarchive the patterns in my iPhone app, using code such as:

  `pattern = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"test.pat"];`

However, when I try to unarchive the objects from this file, all that is returned is `nil`.  I thought I might have had the file path wrong and also tried `@"Resources/test.pat"` to no avail.

Am I simply referring to the file incorrectly?  Or are archived objects simply not cross-platform?  Is this whole approach just plain wrong?  If so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the compatibility of archiving across platforms, but to refer to a bundle resource, you should always use NSBundle to find it. Don't depend on the current path.

Comment: Thanks, Chuck! You hit the nail on the head.  So for those who were curious, archived objects do seem to work across platforms.  I used the following code which worked:

    pattern = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pat"]];

Answer (score 1):

As your model is just an array of arrays, you could use XML property lists which do work across architectures.

Comment: I do exactly this (save property lists on OS X and read them on the iPhone) in one of my applications.